# Edit request before sending it in browser

Tags: rest, http

So I click a button that generates a http request, but before sending it I would like to edit its parameters.

I tried to use postman for chrome and similar addons for firefox, but I did not really understand how to carry out what I need.

Is there a simple way to do what I want?

Comment: Is it a GET request? Are the 'parameters' query parameters or HTTP Headers?

Answer (score 0):

The 'Advanced REST Client' for Chrome allows you to state the REST URL along with any query parameters, the HTTP Method and optionally any HTTP Headers.